# Entity framework, find method leaves foreign key empty

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity named PageItem. PageItem has a property named Page. Type of Page is Page class.

```
       class PageItem {
           public Page Page { get; set; }
           ...
       }
```

when I query like this:

```
var item = context.PageItems.Find(5);
```

Problem is, item.Page is null, so when I save item entity framework creates a new page record.

Comment: This article describes the problem and possible solutions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: include adds a join. i dont want that join for two reasons. One, performance, two there are many properties like page. For example, customer C{get; set;}, city cty {get; set;} So I have to make many Include("...") calls.

Comment: I updated my answer above.

Comment: thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of what I learned:

First: entity framework Find method does not fill Id value of nested objects (in database language: foreign keys. But I realized than when you save that entity, it does not update foreign key columns, so nothing is broken.

Seconly: if you want to read, and use foregin key values of an entity, you should define (int/long whatever) properties per referanced table an foreign key. And mark it with ForeignKey attribute. Also if it can be null, make property type int? or long? (nullable)

Sample:

```
    pubclic class Customer {
        public Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("City")}
        public int? City_Id { get; set; }
        public City City { get; set; } 
    }
```

Also if you want layz loading on City, you have to mark it virtual.